# Toggle Window Open and Close MouseOver and MouseOut

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a div. I want to open a window on mouse over and want to close the window on Mouse Out.I have tried to do, using the following JavaScript function:

```
 function showProducts(id) {
         var myWindow = null;
         if (id = 1) {
             myWindow = window.open("../DataView.aspx", '_blank', "width=500, height=200")
         }
         else
             myWindow.close();

     }
```

I am calling the function from ASPX page using the following :

```
  string script =   string.Format(@"onmouseover=""showProducts(1);""onmouseout=""showProducts(-1);""");
```

But my window is not getting closed on MouseOut event. How to write thw Javascript function to Toggle between opening and closing window on MouseOver and MouseOut?

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors.

1. Your if conditional has a syntax error.

   You must replace `if (batchid = 1)` **by this** `if (batchid === 1)`
2. The `myWindow` var should be declared outside the function because if not any time you call `showProducts` the reference will be overwritten.
3. In the if sentence, you are asking for a `batchid` var which does not exists because your param in the function declaration is called `id`.

**So your function should look like this.**

```
var myWindow = null;

function showProducts(id) {   
   if (id === 1) myWindow = window.open("../DataView.aspx", '_blank', "width=500, height=200")
   else myWindow.close();
}
```

Comment: Your code still has errors. Try whit the code that I posted. Notice that when you call window.open, the new window will get the focus so your mouseout event will not be fire until you return the focus to the original window.

Answer (score -1):

I guess your problem is sequence of your elements in DOM tree, becuase of which events are not getting tunneled to the .
Always keep the  over the opened window, then I think your event will work.

Comment: Sorry but this is not the origin of the issue.